# Quotation marks in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: command-line, 9.04, special-characters

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 as a guest in VMWare. When I am using quotations marks in terminal, the first pressing of the key produces nothing, while the second one produces a double quotation mark looking like the ones from the keyboard, but different from the ones I already have in some text documents. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably has to do with "Dead keys".
Go to Menu>System>Preferences>Keyboard click the tab labeled "layout" and try to add a different keybord layout (I have no clue if this helps for a Romanian keybord layout).

Alternatively, try to press space afterwards (instead of pressing the key twice).

Comment: It's a "deadkey" keyboard layout that does this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the terminal might be using start and end quotes instead of just quotation marks... Which is odd. And wrong. Why it's doing this, is beyond me, and I can't think of a solution other than copying and pasting.